# MySQL Random Select Query with limit returning different number of results (undesired)

Tags: mysql, random

I have a MySQL table with names in it. I am trying to get a random list of names in random order from the table, without a big hit to performance. I found a query that does this and have implemented it, but with one flaw... Say I have 10 names in the database and I request 2 random names using the query. I usually get 2 back, but sometimes I only get one. This of course gets worse if I ask for say 9 names back. I'll get 5, then the next time 8, then 9, then 2. I believe that this has something to do with the script selecting a random id and then going up from there, the issue is that I want to have exactly the number of names back that I request each and every time (Unless the database doesn't contain enough names, in which case it returns all of the names, but in a random order.)

Here is the query I am using:

```
SELECT Name 
FROM RandomNames AS r1 
JOIN (
    SELECT (Rand() * (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM RandomNames)) AS ID
) AS r2 
WHERE r1.ID >= r2.ID 
ORDER BY r1.ID AS C 
LIMIT ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select name from (SELECT Rand() temp, Name 
FROM RandomNames) a order by  temp  
LIMIT ?
```

How about this?